# What does it mean In FX trading you using a T/N swap to avoid physical delivery of the currency?

Tags: fx, derivatives, trading, swaps

I understand you use T/N swaps to rollover FX positions and so avoid physical delivery but I dont quite get how this happens in reality. For example, if I am long EURUSD and need to deliver/sell USD at t+2, to avoid this I can use a T/N swap, so what would I swap with?

Comment: that only partially explains what I asked. In particular, I would like to know (if possible) exactly which T/N swap transaction is done to avoid the physical delivery for an example trade (e.g. long EURUSD).

Comment: In simple terms: You have an obligation with counterparty X to pay USD and receive EUR on Oct 12. You make a deal with counterparty Y that he will do those things on your behalf and then you will pay him some USD and receive some EUR from him on October 13. So Mr. Y is substituted in your place for one day. Not sure what details you are looking for ? Pehaps you would like an example with actual numbers ?

Comment: I'm totally new to FX so sorry for my ignorance. I understand in a FX swap at inception ccy A is exchanged for ccy B (1st leg) and then swapped back at expiry (2nd leg). I'm trying to understand what ccy is swapped with what ccy in a chronological order(step by step). OCT 10: I go long EURUSD. OCT 11: I opt to avoid physical delivery due on T+2 (Oct 12) so enter into a TN swap with Y. OCT 12: counterparty Y takes care of on my behalf (Y gives USD to X and gets EUR from X? 1st leg of the swap?), OCT 13 I give USD to Y and receive EUR from Y (where did I get the USD from? 2nd leg of the swap?).